# Giving error while executing shell script like syntax error at line `(' unexpected

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to run script but its giving me error as `(' unexpected ,What changes should i do for it

'ps -f -u "$USER" | grep "icsmpgum" | grep -v grep | awk '{printf (":%d:", $2)}' | xargs kill -9'

Comment: Don't add single quotes before `ps` or after `-9`

Comment: Also... `awk { printf ":%d", $2 }`. Not sure why you think that needs to be parenthesized... `awk != C`...

Comment: @twalberg,  you have both printf statement and function: `awk 'BEGIN {printf "%s ", "hello"; printf("%s\n","world")}'`

Comment: @glenn : can u please tell me , If i want to kill the process after it is executed properly and then i want to kill that process , so that which kill signal should i use here ?

Comment: `-9` is the nuclear option. Start with `kill -INT` that is the equivalent of ctrl-C

Comment: If the process is running then -9 killed process on half of it, without completing the process , But I want to killed it after completion of it , Is their any signal used like SIGUSR1 ,SIGHUP